# Pycallgraph with Spyder does not work

Tags: python, spyder

I ran the below code verbatim (which is an official sample code): 
http://pycallgraph.slowchop.com/en/master/examples/basic.html

And I get the below error:

> 'The command "{}" is required to be in your path.'.format(cmd))
>   pycallgraph.exceptions.PyCallGraphException: The command "dot" is
>   required to be in your path.

I'm running the program in Spyder on Windows from the directory : '*C:\MyDocs\pleasework.py*'

'*C:\MyDocs*' is present in the sys.path as well

Answer (score 2):

The pycallgraph module tries to use the dot command, which is not available in your system. You should install the dot utility which is provided by the graphviz package.
 http://www.graphviz.org/Download_windows.php

Comment: This worked for me but with the additional step of making dot command available in the PATH.